# Problema al insertar datos (duplicación)

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien he estado en las pruebas y fallos para así seguir avanzando en primer app, al momento de realizar el insertar datos a una tabledlayout, esta me la muestra bien, pero cuando me dirijo a la base de datos me percato que esta se duplica.
Para empezar les presento el arreglo json en php que se llama insertar_presupuesto2:

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
require("conexion1.php");
$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Filas=$_POST['N_Filas'] ?? null;
$Cant = $_POST['Cant_Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Repuestos = $_POST['Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Valor = $_POST['Valor_Repuestos'] ?? null;
$Original = $_POST['Valor_Original'] ?? null;
$Alternativo = $_POST['Valor_Alternativo'] ?? null;
$Patente = $_POST['Patente_Vehiculo'] ?? null;
$Activo = $_POST['Activo'] ?? null;
$consulta = "INSERT into presupuesto2
(N_Filas,Cant_Repuestos,Repuestos,Valor_Repuestos,Valor_Original,Valor_Alternativo,Patente_Vehiculo,Activo)
values ('".$Filas."','".$Cant."','".$Repuestos."','".$Valor."','".$Original."','".$Alternativo."','".$Patente."','".$Activo."')";
echo "se graban los datos";
mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

al probarlo en postmann me funciona muy bien, lo hice con varios registros, pero al momento de llevarlo al android, me da el problema ,este es el procedimiento a utilizar en android que utilizo:

```
cmdingresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.1.90/gestion/insertar_presupuesto2.php");
        }
    });
```

posteriormente el ejecutar...:

```
private void ejecutarServicio (String URL) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String cantidad,repuesto,valor;
    cantidad = txtcantidad.getText().toString();
    repuesto = txtrepuesto3.getText().toString();
    valor = txtvalor2.getText().toString();
    if (cantidad.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo de la cantidad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtcantidad.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (repuesto.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del repuesto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtrepuesto3.requestFocus();
        return;
    } else if (valor.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Error, debe ingresar el campo del valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtvalor2.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, response -> {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Datos grabados satisfactoriamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
        cmdingresar.setEnabled(false);
        datos();
        insertar();
    }, error -> Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String a = "1";
            n.setText(a);
            String b = "0";
            k.setText(b);
            String c = "0";
            l.setText(c);
            parametros.put("N_Filas",txtitem3.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Cant_Repuestos",txtcantidad.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Repuestos",txtrepuesto3.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Valor_Repuestos",txtvalor2.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Valor_Original",k.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Valor_Alternativo",l.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Patente_Vehiculo",m.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("Activo",n.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void datos (){
    String[]item = new String[]{txtitem3.getText().toString(),txtcantidad.getText().toString(),txtrepuesto3.getText().toString(),txtvalor2.getText().toString()};
    tableDynamic.addItems(item);
}

private void insertar (){
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    builder.setMessage("¿Desea seguir ingresando?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            int b = 1;
            int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(txtitem3.getText()));
            int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b));
            int suma = val1 + val2;
            String valorTotal = Integer.toString(suma);
            txtitem3.setText(valorTotal);
            txtcantidad.setText("");
            txtrepuesto3.setText("");
            txtvalor2.setText("");
            txtcantidad.requestFocus();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            txtcantidad.setText("");
            txtrepuesto3.setText("");
            txtvalor2.setText("");
            cmdsuma.setEnabled(true);
            cmdsuma.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Gestión");
    alert.show();
}
```

yo pienso que de acuerdo a mi ignorancia en este tema, el problema esta en esta línea el return parametros; ya que debe haber algún método para terminar este proceso y se dirija al mensaje: ya que al momento de realizarlo paso a paso, es decir línea a línea no me presenta ningún error, o mensaje que este haciendo esto, cabe también mencionar que en el tabledlayout por ejemplo me muestra el N° de Filas con su correspondiente número y demás datos ingresados y no los presenta repetidos, pero al momento de dirigirme a la tabla de datos realizada en mysql me muestra la insercción de datos repetidos, ojala que me puedan ayudar y desde ya muchas gracias.
POor otro aldo se me habia olvida mencionarles algo importante que en la tabla de datos llamada presupuesto2, tengo in ID que es la clave y este a su vez es autoincrementable, además realice el día de hoy todo el proceso desde el return parametros, el cual entra al request.va.a Hurl.java, al Basicnetwork y terin este proceso graba y posteriormente vuelva al return parametros en donde se puso la bandera y vuelve a ingresar todo el proceso antes mencionado, he ehecho de todos estos dós días, y nada siempre el mismo error, e incluso realice toda la clase java desde cero, pensando que podía estar el efrror en algun lado y nada sigue tal cual, con la duplicidad de ingresos a la tabla de datos, ojala que me puedan ayudar y nuevamente muchas gracias.